# Custom Input Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

This is BaseInput.vue's template, as you know in Vue3 we have **$attrs** (fallthrough props) that we can specify where to bind prop value as below I bind it to  element with the intention of customize css style for input element. 
BaseInput.vue

```
<template>
  <label :class="$style.wrapper">
    <input
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :value="modelValue"
    />
    <span :class="$style.label">
      <slot name="label"></slot>
    </span>
  </label>
</template>
```

Then I call

```
<BaseInput
  v-model="username"
  :class="$style.field"
  />
<BaseInput
  v-model="password"
  :class="$style.field"
  / >
```

So basically the class `field` will be applied to <input/ > element in BaseInput.vue component thanks to `v-bind='$attrs'`.
But sometimes, I want to add css style for the wrapper element of BaseInput.vue (here is  element).
For example:

```
  margin-bottom: 32px;
```

I want the first  has margin bottom = 32px, but the second one doesn't.
So what is the good way to achive that?

I just found a solution that we add a div wrapper for each  but I think it's not really good idea. So please elaborate me.

Comment: There may be multiple class props. It's more likely that you need only one, with `class` being to be applied to a parent, while a child can be styled based on that with nested selectors, e.g. `myclass > label > input`

Comment: @EstusFlask
Yeah it's a nice solution, I already used it. Thank you so much.